# Directly comparing two images, when one has an alpha channel?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Basically I have two images; one small image (I'll call it Image 1), and a screenshot. I've been searching the screen for instances of Image 1 using Python and OpenCV, in particular the *cv2.matchTemplate* function.

The issue is that *matchTemplate*, so far as I understand, requires that the images be in grayscale. So to ensure that the images are the same, I grayscale both Image 1 and the screenshot, find instances using *matchTemplate*, and then compare the results to the original Image 1  to ensure the colours match.

So here is the problem; OpenCV has a *compare* function that looked like it would do the trick for the final comparison; but Image 1 is basically a sprite, and has relevant alpha information, and *compare* seems to simply perform an elementwise comparison of two multi-dimensional arrays. The screenshot does not have an alpha channel and so the two can't be compared that way, since they are different sizes. Moreover I can't just add an alpha to the screenshotted image since ultimately I'm not trying to compare alpha channels, im trying to ignore pixels **with** an alpha channel during comparison.

So basically I want to know;
a) If it's possible to use *matchTemplate* or something similar to search the screen using colour images, or b) if there is a comparison function already written somewhere that compares images only where the images are visible when rendered.

I'll make an Imgur account if you need visual examples of what I'm on about.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know OpenCV well. But you can do that in ImageMagick, though it is not as fast as OpenCV. And it works on color images not just grayscale ones.

ImageMagick 7 can do a masked compare (where the mask would be extracted from the alpha channel of the one image). ImageMagick has a number of correlation metrics for its compare template matching including rmse (root mean squared error) and ncc (normalized cross correlation).

Small Image (without alpha):

[image]

Mask Image (extracted from alpha):

[image]

Large Image:

[image]

```
magick compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 large.png \( -read-mask small_mask.png small.png \) diff.png

0 (0) @ 417,44
```

Here I use the rmse metric. The numbers 0 (0) are raw scores (16-bit range) and scores normalized to the range 0 to 1 (in parentheses). The fact that they are zero means a perfect match. The values after @ are the location of the best match.

Two output images are produced. The first shows highlighted in red on the large image where there are differences (no red in this case, since a perfect match). The second shows the correlation surface image. The brightest pixel is where the best match occurs.

[image]

[image]

Here is another example where I add a white line to the small image:

Small Image 2:

[image]

```
magick compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 large.png \( -read-mask small_mask.png small2.png \) diff2.png

4159.53 (0.0634704) @ 417,44
```

Now you can see the red line in the first output image that shows where they differ in the best match location. Note that the line only shows inside the hat, since the mask prevented the correlation from using pixels in its black area.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The masked compare is exactly what I was looking for. I'm wondering if it might be faster to perform the template matching in greyscale and then perform my own masked compare afterwards, rather than importing another library and doing the whole thing in colour. I guess it depends how many hits I'm expecting. For now I'm extracting the alpha channel and performing the comparison myself rather than using ImageMagick, but I'll definitely take a look later and see if this cleans things up a bit better.

Comment: OpenCV template matching does permit color images to be  matched. You do not need grayscale. But I am unaware of it permitting masking during the template match, that is no mask argument seems to be available.

Comment: Actually, I just found some recent documentation for OpenCV 3.4 that does imply that masking can be used. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html. See also https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be

Comment: I'm not sure how I managed to miss all that. Should be able to get it working. Still would be nice to have masking in compare but I probably missed that too.